# Is this counter example is valid or did I miss something?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Let $S,T :\mathbb{C^5} \to \mathbb{C^4}$ such the for every $v\neq0$ :

$T(v)\neq 0$ or $S(v)\neq 0$ (or both of them).

Is it true that there must exist $u\neq0 \in \mathbb{C^4}$ such that $u \in IM(S)\cap IM(T)$ ?

I think this is not true, and for counter example I can defind $e_i$ as the standard basis for $C^5$ and define the following transformations:
$$T(e_i) = (1,0,0,0)$$ for every $1 \leq i \leq 5 $ and than I can define $S$ as the zero transformation, wich means $S=0$ than the only vector in the intersection of the images are the zero vector.

Comment: Considering the dimensions the bets are low that the kernels are trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the transformation you gave is that the condition $T(v)\ne0$ or $S(v)\ne0$ for any $v\ne0$ is not met. For example, $T(e_1-e_2)=S(e_1-e_2)=0$.

This condition, which is given, can be interpreted as $\ker(S)\cap\ker(T)=\{0\}$. You can then deduce that $\dim(\ker(S))+\dim(\ker(T))\le5$. Try playing a bit with the rank-nullity theorem, and you should be able to arrive to the conclusion that $\dim(Im(S)\cap Im(T))\ne0$, which is equivalent to what you want to prove.

Comment: Ohh my mistake. Thank you for pointing that!